# Display release consol output in Logs tab

Tags: tfs

I have a release definition that is conected to a dll file containing unit test methods. These test methods use Trace.WriteLine() to print outputs to console.
When the test methods are DEBUGGED on visual studio the printings are displayed to output window. However when unit test is being RUN on visual studio the printings are displayed only AFTER the run is finished. When release is deployed on TFS the output is printed only to trx file.
Is there a way I can make the output be displayed  DURING the unit test run on visual studio and on TFS,  DURING the release deploynent on the Logs tab?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply  publishes the test results to TFS release summary when tests are running in release pipeline.

> The task supports popular test result formats including JUnit, NUnit
>   2, NUnit 3, **Visual Studio Test (TRX)**, and xUnit 2. If you use the
>   built-in tasks such as Visual Studio Test to run tests, results are
>   automatically published and you do not need a separate publish test
>   results task.

More details please refer [Publish Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=vsts) task.